# Please verify the Proof of "if $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are singular with respect to $\mu$,then so is $c_1\nu_1+c_2\nu_2$"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> Show that if $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are singular with respect to
> $\mu$,then so is $c_1\nu_1+c_2\nu_2$

$\nu_1\perp\mu\implies$ there are disjoint measurable sets $A_1$ and $B_1$ such that $X=A_1\cup B
_1$ and $\mu(B_1)=0=\nu_1(A_1)$

Similarly,$\nu_2\perp\mu\implies$ there are disjoint measurable sets $A_2$ and $B_2$ such that $X=A_2\cup B_2$ and $\mu(B_2)=0=\nu_1(A_2)$

So,$X=(A_1\cap A_2)\cup(B_1\cup B_2)$ and $(A_1\cap A_2)\cap(B_1\cap B_2)=\phi$

**$(c_1\nu_1+c_2\nu_2)(A_1\cap A_2)=c_1\nu_1(A_1\cap A_2)+c_2\nu_2(A_1\cap A_2)=c_1\times 0+c_2\times 0=0$ [as  $A_1\cap A_2\subset A_1,A_2$]**

and
$\mu(B_1\cup B_2)=\mu(B_1/B_2)+\mu(B_2)=\mu(B_1/B_2)+0=0$[as $B_1/B_2\subset B_1$]

*is the above proof correct?*

Comment: The "solution-verification" tag is not for posts that ask for a review of a completed argument. Please read the description of the tag: "or posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so."

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach is to say $\mu \perp \nu \iff$ there exists $B$ such that $\mu(B) = 0$ and $\nu(X \setminus B) = 0$.

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be witnesses to $\nu_1, \nu_2 \perp \mu$ respectively. Then $$\mu(B_1 \cup B_2) = 0$$ and $$\left(c_1\nu_1 + c_2 \nu_2\right)(X \setminus (B_1 \cup B_2)) \leq c_1\nu_1(X \setminus B_1) + c_2\nu_2(X \setminus B_2) = 0$$

which shows that $\mu \perp c_1 \nu_1 + c_2 \nu_2$.